# I am trying to read data from a html textarea in python. The data in UTf-8 format that I cannot convert

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

This is the UTF representation I get back for the textarea:

```
%23+Subject

%23+Git%0D%0A%0D%0AGit+is+a+version+contro
```

I am really not sure how to convert this to ascii.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular encoding is called url encoding, it can be decoded with [urllib.parse.unquote_plus](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote_plus) as such:

```py
from urllib.parse import unquote_plus

s = """
%23+Subject

%23+Git%0D%0A%0D%0AGit+is+a+version+contro
"""

unquote_plus(s)
```

Yielding:

```
# Subject

# Git

Git is a version contro
```